# Excel macro - move file (fix code)

Tags: file, excel, move, vba

i have this code:

```
Sub MoveFiles()
Dim d As String, ext, x
Dim srcPath As String, destPath As String, srcFile As String
srcPath = "C:\test\"
destPath = "C:\test2\"
ext = Array("*.csv", "*.xls")
For Each x In ext
d = Dir(srcPath & x)
    Do While d <> ""
        srcFile = srcPath & d
        FileCopy srcFile, destPath & d
        Kill srcFile
        d = Dir
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

but it deletes every single file in srcPath. i only need it to delete activeworkbook.name and not every single one.
ive thought about this code for a good hour and cant figure out how to make it not loop and still do what it should.

i appreciate some help on this

Comment: `i only need it to delete activeworkbook.name and not every single one.` How can you delete the activeworkbook if you are running the code from it?

Comment: because it has already saved it to another place. i just specified what the name would be

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to kill a specific file then why use a loop that kills every file in its iteration?

if you want to kill a specific file and still loop then you need to add an "if" clause
something like:

```
if srcFile = activewindow.name then
    kill
else
    do nothing
end if
```

Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: no, its not about killing the file. its about first moving the file to a specified folder, and delete the file from the previous folder

Comment: got it. it kills every file instead just killing the file at the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: i've tried your code. it copied the files to the destination folder and then killed it from the origin path. what is that you're trying to kill? you cannot kill the active sheet, it's protected because it's open and running the code from it.

Comment: say that the filename is stored in R and after ive saved all files they are not with the name R anymore. and i could kill of R alone in a folder where there are multiple files.